# How to select a url from a list box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

On the back button click event the web browser is suppossed to go to the first item on the list(back one page). I coded this in VB and it works, but on in C# where my app is it doesn't.

this is my code:

```
      private void back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        web.Navigate(new Uri(hlist.Items.First, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

-web is the name of my web browser

-hlist is the list of history

- GoBack is not supported in windows phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making a variable i and instead of making the webbrowser going to First, try making it so it's like: `i--` so `hlist.SelectedItem=i` or something then you can say `i--` then make the webbrowser navigate to i, the value of the hlist.  I haven't done c# in a while, so `hlist.SelectedItem=i` might not work.

Comment: I've tried the variables but they don't work this is what I have-                     private void hlist_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            hlist.SelectedItem = "targetUrl";
            Uri targetUri = new Uri ("targetUrl", UriKind.Absolute);
            web.Navigate(targetUri);
        }